# Kerberos parameter in sparklyr livy protocol

Tags: azure, kerberos, azure-hdinsight, sparklyr, livy

I want to connect with a domain joined HDInsight cluster in Azure from a domain joined VM. Unfortunately, I don't know how to make sure that `sparklyr` starts a session with Kerberos authentication.

```r
sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(master = "****:8998",method = "livy",config = livy_conf)
```

Which parameter can I use in order to specify the Kerberos protocol?